# How do I get a link from FireBase? C#

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I work with the C# language not java and do not yet know how to get a reference to an object in FireBaseStorage. I have the following code that should output a link from Fire Base Storage, but instead it outputs System.Threading.Tasks.Tast`1[The system.Line]

Tell me how do I get a link to a file from FireBaseStorage using FireSharp and FireBase libraries

here is my code: (C#)

```
            FirebaseStorage storage = new FirebaseStorage("*******-****.appspot.com");
            var starsRef = storage.Child("test.txt");
            string link = starsRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(link);
```

Comment: Don't know above java C# taht much, but whenever we do an asynchronous calls, don't we have to wait for result ? "await". Cause your ouput seems your thread is waiting for the result. System.Threading.Tasks.Tast`1[The system.Line]

Comment: Try using await before getting downloadUrl ```string link = await starsRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ToString();``` and make your mehtod asynchronous in which you are writing your code.

Comment: Yes, please if it works let me know I will put my comment as answer

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File String Suppression Status
Error CS1929 "string" does not contain a definition for "GetAwaiter", and the most appropriate overloaded extension method "Await.GetAwaiter(Task)" requires a recipient of type "Task". FireBaseOnli C:\Users\Egorf\source\repos\FireBaseOnli\MainForm.cs 1292 Active

Comment: HOORAY, how long I have been tormented with this question, and I can say that you were right!, only it was necessary to remove toString(). Thanks! Adding a respon
```

```

Comment: private void button28_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a reference to the file we want to download
            _ = getLinkAsync();
            getLinkAsync();

        }
        public async Task getLinkAsync()
        {
            FirebaseStorage storage = new FirebaseStorage("firstbd-***.appspot.com");
            var starsRef = storage.Child("test.txt");
            string link = await starsRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(link);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know above C# that much, but whenever we do an asynchronous calls, don't we have to wait for result ? "await". Cause your ouput seems your thread is waiting for the result. System.Threading.Tasks.Tast`1[The system.Line]

Try using await before getting downloadUrl string link = await starsRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ToString(); and make your mehtod asynchronous in which you are writing your code.

C#

```
        private void button28_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a reference to the file we want to download
            _ = getLinkAsync();
            getLinkAsync();

        }
        public async Task getLinkAsync()
        {
            FirebaseStorage storage = new FirebaseStorage("firstbd-****.appspot.com");
            var starsRef = storage.Child("test.txt");
            string link = await starsRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(link);
        }
```